# "Formatted value of the cell has a wrong type" error when inherit DataGridViewCheckBoxCell even when the class implement nothing

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

The code is

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace MyDataGridView
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CheckBoxColumn col = new CheckBoxColumn();
            //DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            col.ValueType = typeof(bool);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);                
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[]{true});
        }
    }
    public class CheckBoxCell : DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
    {
        /*public CheckBoxCell()
        {
            ThreeState = false;
            TrueValue = 1;
            FalseValue = 0;
        }*/
    }
    public class CheckBoxColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
        public CheckBoxColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = new CheckBoxCell();
        }
    }
}
```

the Form1 has a datagridview named dataGridView1

when I change the 'col' variable to DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn everything is OK

I subclass the class to provide some custom painting on the cells

Comment: Are you getting this error while compiling the code or while run the code? While line of code gives the error?

Comment: The error appeared at compiled time, and it only show the error message but not show the line where the error occured

Comment: If I change the parent class of CheckBoxColumn to DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn then it is OK too